# Padding property within my <TextBox> does not apply any value entered into the property

Tags: wpf, textbox, padding

I've done the below code for a textbox which contains a image within it and I want to apply right padding at value of 20 so that the text does not overlap the icon, but it doesn't seem to work. I've tried it with the padding property existing only under the top `<TextBox>` or when it exists only within my `<TextBox.Style>` as well as both as per below code and none of these combinations work.

```
                    <TextBox x:Name="txtUser"
                         FontSize="13"
                         FontWeight="Medium"
                         FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                         Foreground="White"
                         CaretBrush="LightGray"
                         Height="28"
                         VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                         Margin="0,5,0,0"
                         Padding="20,0,0,0">
                    <TextBox.Background>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="/Images/user-icon.png"
                                    Stretch="None"
                                    AlignmentX="Left"/>
                    </TextBox.Background>

                    <TextBox.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#5b69bc"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
                            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20,0,0,0"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#6e82ef"/>
                                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,1"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="20,0,0,0"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBox.Style>
                </TextBox>
```

I'm struggling to figure out why the padding would not apply in this scenario.

Comment: Do you mean the Background Brush should be affected by the Padding?

Comment: @Clemens I realised I didn't specifically say... the padding needs to apply to the text entered into the textbox so that it doesn't overlap the icon which is in the `<ImageBrush>`

Answer (score -1):

If you want the `Background` of your control to have padding, you can cheat a little with the `VisualBrush`. With it, you can "paint" using other UI elements.

For example, you can paint using a `Grid` with two columns. First column, with `Width=20` is your "padding". In the second one there is a rectangle with your background image:

```
    <TextBox
        Name="txtUser"
        Height="28"
        Margin="0,5,0,0"
        Padding="20,0,0,0"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
        CaretBrush="LightGray"
        FontFamily="Segoe UI"
        FontSize="13"
        FontWeight="Medium"
        Foreground="White">
        <TextBox.Background>
            <VisualBrush AlignmentX="Left" Stretch="None">
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Grid
                        Width="{Binding ElementName=txtUser, Path=ActualWidth}"
                        Height="{Binding ElementName=txtUser, Path=ActualHeight}"
                        Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Rectangle Grid.Column="1">
                            <Rectangle.Fill>
                                <ImageBrush
                                    AlignmentX="Left"
                                    ImageSource="/Images/user-icon.png"
                                    Stretch="None" />
                            </Rectangle.Fill>
                        </Rectangle>
                    </Grid>
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </TextBox.Background>
```

Notice that:

- since the `Visual` in the `VisualBrush` knows nothing of its container, you have set its `Width` and `Height` (here, they're bound to the parent `TetxBox`'s `ActualHeight` and `ActualWidth`)
- The `Background` of the inner `Grid` is set (here: to `Transparent`). If you don't do this, the brush won't "see" the padding column anyway

**EDIT:**

If you're talking about `Padding` on the text itself, the code you provided as example works as expected, and the padding is applied properly.

In that case, you should either set the `Padding` directly or in `Style`, not both. If you set both, the ones in `Style` & `Trigger` will be ignored.